# AngularJS - ng-grid - Date Column issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datepicker, ng-grid

[UPDATED DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/CRJy7fsPTO0wvSAksYLu?p=preview)

I am using Angular ui-grid http://ui-grid.info/. There is one column `Date of Birth` which needs `DatePicker` when in edit mode.

When i click on the column it shows me `Date Picker` but the selected date value doesn't get selected in Date picker. Also also Date Picker doesn't get removed after edition is complete.

```
columnDefs: [
      { field: 'name' },
      {
        field: 'dob',
        cellFilter: 'date',
        enableCellEdit: true,
        editableCellTemplate: '<input type="date" />'
      }
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate-  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20983948/how-to-use-bootstrap-datepicker-inside-ng-grid

Comment: I checked the link, No perfect answer there..!

Answer (score 3):

you need `editableCellTemplate` options in your columnDef to set the template depending on what datepicker plugin you are using. takinig [ui-bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) as example (it's not viable until you prepare the scope variables)

```
columnDefs: [
    { field: 'name' },
    {
        field: 'dob',
        cellFilter: 'date',
        enableCellEdit: true,
        editableCellTemplate: '<input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="\'2015-06-22\'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />'
    },
    ...
]
```

Comment: alright, since `ng-grid` is messed up bits and going to be replaced by it's revolution version `ui-grid`, i strongly recommended you to use `ui-grid` instead. i will attach another answer for `ui.grid`

Comment: Lots of coding being done....Can't replace the `ui-grid`..!! Is there any solution?

Comment: i am a deep ng-grid user, lots of works will be involved dealing with editable fields, you might probably need to write a directive for native html datepicker to handle the things like focus status and use `ng-model` to binding the date selected. further more, when you have pinning function and more than 20 columns, you will feel painful living with ng-grid...

Answer (score 1):

try `ui-grid` which is a next generation `ng-grid` refactored by the same guys. it's well designed and loosely coupled by plugins:

html:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Custom Plunker</title>  
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.11/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid-unstable.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid-unstable.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-edit class="grid"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.grid', 'ui.grid.edit']);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", dob: '1985-01-01'},
                 {name: "Tiancum", dob: '1956-11-21'},
                 {name: "Jacob", dob: '1980-03-08'},
                 {name: "Nephi", dob: '1974-08-08'},
                 {name: "Enos", dob: '1991-07-17'}];

  $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'myData',
    // rowTemplate: '<div ng-style="{ \'cursor\': row.cursor }" ng-repeat="col in renderedColumns" ng-class="col.colIndex()" class="ngCell {{col.cellClass}}" style="overflow: visible"><div class="ngVerticalBar" ng-style="{height: rowHeight}" ng-class="{ ngVerticalBarVisible: !$last }">&nbsp;</div><div ng-cell></div></div>',
    columnDefs: [
      {
        name: 'dob',
        displayName: 'DOB',
        cellFilter: 'date',
        type: 'date'

      },
      { name: 'name' , displayName: 'Name'}
    ]
  }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try placing `<input type="date" />` into a directive. And use the directive inside the grid.

I remember this has worked for me. NG-grid tends to swallow certain events and selecting a date might not work if done without a directive.